# How to access Value in a JSON string using a Key in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, string

Python code:

```
import json
aaa='''
{
    "eee":"yes",
    "something": null,
    "ok": ["no","mmm","eee"],
    "please":false,
    "no": {"f":true,"h":"ttt"}
}
'''
data=json.loads(aaa)
```

When I do:

```
print(len(data))
```

I get as expected:

```
5
```

and

```
print(len(data['ok']))
```

which gives

```
3
```

But somehow

```
print(data[0])
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(data[0])
KeyError: 0
```

How do I get a term inside this JSON object using its index?

Comment: Indexing requires a list.

Comment: the reason you are getting `KeyError ` is because you do not have `0` as key in your `dictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about *access a position in a JSON*, but the `data` structure is python `dict`, with key and values, you can index it only using it's keys as you did well with `data['ok']`.

To get *first* key, you can first get the `dict.items()`, which is a list of the pairs `key/value`, and then, as it's a `list` you ca index with ints

```
data.items()
# [('eee', 'yes'), ('something', None), ('ok', ['no', 'mmm', 'eee']), ('please', False), ('no', {'f': True, 'h': 'ttt'})]


items = list(data.items())
items[0]
# ('eee', 'yes')
```

Comment: While the latest versions of Python maintain dict key insertion order, it is not guaranteed in older versions.  The C implementation of Python 3.6 first maintained key order as an implementation detail, and order is standard in Python 3.7.  Don't expect other implementations of 3.6 and any implementation of 3.5 and older to return 'eee' for item[0].

Answer (score 1):

Python Dictionaries are Unordered. It means you can't access the dictionary element based on its index value. You need to provide key to access the corresponding value or values.

Comment: Python dictionaries as of 3.7 maintain insertion order.  While they can't be indexed, they can be iterated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

You can get the term inside the `JSON` by specifying the `Key` value of the data. Here, `eee` is the `Key`:

```
print((data['eee']))
```

which will print:

```
yes
```

similarly you can use other `Key` to get their respective values.

The `JSON` data is formatted as `Key:Value`